# Pycharm: writing data from serial to Google sheets using gspread - not working

Tags: google-api, pycharm, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have this code that worked for someone else (he is not available FOR CONSULTATION)

```
import logging
import random
import time
import serial
import os
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import datetime

__author__ = "Ofek Weinberger & Ziv Beker"
__copyright__ = "Copyright (C) 2020 Ofek Weinberger & Ziv Beker"
__license__ = "Public Domain"
__version__ = "1.0"

def init_connection(ser, last_experiment=None):
    """
    This function is used to initialize the connection with google's system.
    :param ser: The reference to the serial object we use to communicate with the ATMega328P
    :param last_experiment: If none - it is a normal experiment but else can be used to             continue a running experiment
    :return:
    """
    # Use credentials to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
    scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)

    # Make sure you use the right name here
    spread_sheet = client.open("EXPERIMENTS")
    init_experiment(ser, spread_sheet, last_experiment=last_experiment)


def init_experiment(ser, spread_sheet, last_experiment=None):
    """
    This function is used to initialize the experiment: create a new worksheet for the         
 experiment and set it up.
    :param ser: The reference to the serial object we use to communicate with the ATMega328P
    :param spread_sheet: The spreadsheet of the experiment.
    :param last_experiment: If none - it is a normal experiment but else can be used to continue a running experiment
    :return:
    """
    experiment_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    print(spread_sheet.title + "@" + experiment_time)
    logging.log(100, spread_sheet.title + "@" + experiment_time)

    # create new worksheet
    if last_experiment is None:
        worksheet = spread_sheet.add_worksheet(title="experiment@" + experiment_time+'END',     rows=10000, cols=10)
    else:
        worksheet = spread_sheet.worksheet(last_experiment[0])
    # add titles
    worksheet.update_acell('A1', 't')
    worksheet.update_acell('B1', 'T_in')
    worksheet.update_acell('C1', 'T_out')
    worksheet.update_acell('D1', 'T_aux')
    worksheet.update_acell('E1', 'RH_in')
    worksheet.update_acell('F1', 'RH_out')
    worksheet.update_acell('G1', 'RH_aux')
    worksheet.update_acell('I1', 'WaterLevel')

    print("t, T_in, T_out, T_aux, RH_in, RH_out, RH_aux,WaterLevel")
    logging.log(100, "t, T_in, T_out, T_aux, RH_in, RH_out, RH_aux,WaterLevel")

    # start experiment loop
    if last_experiment is None:
        start_experiment(ser, worksheet=worksheet)
    else:
        start_experiment(ser, worksheet=worksheet, worksheet_row=last_experiment[1])


def start_experiment(ser, worksheet, worksheet_row=2):
    """
    The experiment loop, measure the sensors and update the sheet.
    :param ser: The reference to the serial object we use to communicate with the ATMega328P
    :param worksheet: The specific sheet we edit
    :param worksheet_row: The row we're writing at
    :return:
    """
    print(worksheet_row)
    while True:
        try:
            # get measurements and cell range:
            measurements = get_measurements(ser)
            print("vals=" + str(measurements))
            logging.log(100, "vals=" + str(measurements))
            cell_list = worksheet.range('A' + str(worksheet_row) + ':H' + str(worksheet_row))

            # update in sheets
            for i in range(len(measurements)):
                cell_list[i].value = measurements[i]
            worksheet.update_cells(cell_list, 'USER_ENTERED')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            logging.log(100, e)
            time.sleep(100)
            init_connection(ser, last_experiment=(worksheet.title, worksheet_row))
        # next row and wait for some time
        worksheet_row += 1
        time.sleep(30)


def get_measurements(ser):
    """
    This function measures the sensors of the experiment
    :param ser: The reference to the serial object we use to communicate with the ATMega328P
    :return: Array of the measurement according to this order: t, T_in, T_out, T_aux, RH_in,         RH_out, RH_aux, Flux,WaterLevel
    """
    t = datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

    # Here we read the data from the sensors
    T_in = random.randint(1, 3)
    T_out = random.randint(1, 10) + 15
    T_aux = random.randint(1, 3) - 5
    RH_in = random.randint(1, 5) + 55
    RH_out = random.randint(1, 5) + 40
    RH_aux = random.randint(1, 5) + 50
    WaterLevel = random.randint(1, 10) + 300
    data = [ser.read()]
    if data[0] != b'':
        newByte = ser.read()
        while newByte != b'':
            data.append(newByte)
            newByte = ser.read()
        data = b''.join(data)
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        print('data_read=' + str(data))
        data = data.split('\n')
        list_of_parameters = ['t=', 'Ti=', 'RHi=', 'To=', 'RHo=', 'Ta=', 'RHa=','WaterLevel='] #need to be exactly the same as written in the arduino serial monitor
        for line in data:
          if any(x not in line for x in list_of_parameters):
            data.remove(line)

        data = data[len(data) - 1]        

        print('data=' + str(data))
        data = data.split(' ')
        uptime = (data[0])[data[0].index('=') + 1:]
        T_in = (data[1])[data[1].index('=') + 1:]
        RH_in = (data[2])[data[2].index('=') + 1:]
        T_out = (data[3])[data[3].index('=') + 1:]
        RH_out = (data[4])[data[4].index('=') + 1:]
        T_aux = (data[5])[data[5].index('=') + 1:]
        RH_aux = (data[6])[data[6].index('=') + 1:]
        WaterLevel = (data[7])[data[7].index('=') + 1:]
    return t, T_in, T_out, T_aux, RH_in, RH_out, RH_aux,WaterLevel


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filename='logs/experiment@' +         datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") +'END'+ '.log', filemode='w',
                        level=100, format="")
    print('Initializing program')
    logging.log(100, 'Initializing program')

    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 115200, timeout=0.1)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Serial connection is okay')
    logging.log(100, 'Serial connection is okay')

    init_connection(ser)
```

It seems like everything is working fine, I'm even getting the log files (with the data that should be written) in my working directory. 
The Google sheets file remains empty, any idea why? 
What is exactly the process of initialization before the gspread can actually write inside the spreadsheet /worksheet??

Any help would be appreciated! (:

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want, for example, how about testing for putting the value to Google Spreadsheet using a simple sample script of gspread?

Comment: i'm also doing that, but i thought there might be just a small modification i didn't do and someone could point out to it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I couldn't understand about your replying. Can I ask you about your current issue?

Comment: i solved the current issue, but you are welcome to ask and i hope i could help (:

my issue was solved once i noticed that when i created the spreadsheet, automatically a worksheet named sheet1 was created, yet my code is creating it's own worksheet for every experiment. 
i simply had to look down at the worksheet tabs in google sheets to find the worksheet that is actually being updated with the correct data!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

so my issue was solved once i noticed that when i created the spreadsheet, automatically a worksheet named sheet1 was created, yet my code is creating it's own worksheet for every experiment. i simply had to look down at the worksheet tabs in google sheets to find the worksheet that is actually being updated with the correct data!